# In node, I have json object called 'errors'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How can I get the first value of json object? The object contains dynamic values and I need always first value of the object

```
errors = {
  state: [ 'The state field is required.' ],
  city: [ 'The city field is required.' ]
}
```

Comment: It's probably an object with the keys being the erroneous fields, and the values being *a list of* problems. What you'd do is you loop through this object, because you don't know what keys you can expect, and then loop through the error messages as well, because you don't know how many there will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values`.

```
let firstValue = Object.values(errors)[0]
```

Comment: Note that this may or may not return the `state` value…

Comment: Sure. but it's what is asked in the question.

Comment: Your answer is not guaranteed to give the OP what they asked in the question; it's not guaranteed that this results in 'The state field is required.'.

Comment: I'm talking about this part: `How can I get the first value of json objec`. But if you think the answer is not correct then I will delete it.